# Floating-point number representation difference between PostgreSQL and Java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I use PostgreSQL 9.4.1 (32-bit, Windows) and have a table with a `real` column - quantity. When I execute the following query on pgAdmin:

`SELECT quantity || ' pcs' FROM table`

I get the following results:

`123.234 psc
123 psc
12 psc
12.3 psc`

Surprisingly, the same query through Java driver `postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc4` (and `postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc3`) is different:

`123.2341 psc
123 psc
12 psc
12.3000002 psc`

As `quantity` is not returned by the query directly (but a string containing it), I don't expect such differences in the results. Can anyone suggest a solution so that Java result is the same as the one from pgAdmin.

Comment: Whatever the cause: a floating point number is imprecise, an approximation, without inherent precision. SQL DECIMAL(_N_,_M_) and java BigDecimal are precise.

Comment: Aside from the obvious (ie. use the appropriate type: `numeric` / `decimal`): the only thing, that can modify the outputs of `float`s (`real` is just an alias), is the [`extra_float_digits`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-EXTRA-FLOAT-DIGITS) setting.

Comment: It seems that extra_float_digits is the problem here :) As for imprecision of real type - yes, I know this, but I wondered why there is a difference in representation of a string (real number concatenated with a string) between pgAndmin and JDBC Driver as I expect string concatenation to return the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like pgAdmin is set to display only 3 trailing digits.

You can use a `DecimalFormat` object in your code to display the data in the same manner.

```
double numberOne = 123.2341;
double numberTwo = 123;
double numberThree = 12;
double numberFour = 12.30000002;

DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat();
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);

System.out.println(formatter.format(numberOne));   // 123.234
System.out.println(formatter.format(numberTwo));   // 123
System.out.println(formatter.format(numberThree)); // 12
System.out.println(formatter.format(numberFour));  // 12.3
```

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL says that the real data type is an *inexact, variable-precision numeric types*, and that *[o]n most platforms, the real type has a range of at least 1E-37 to 1E+37 with a precision of at least 6 decimal digits*, because they use an IEE754 single precision representation with only 24 bits for the mantissa.

That means that *in the database*, 123.234 and 123.2341 are represented by the same value. I assume that you are using `double` datatype in Java, with a precision of about 15 decimal digits. The differences are normal.

If you want the values to be the same, you can try to use simple precision `floats` in Java, but you will still depend on the display modes between Java and pgAdmin.

The only foolproof way to maintain accuracy on decimal values is to use `NUMERIC(precision, scale)` in PostgreSQL, and `BigDecimal` in Java.